# How to Pass dynamic type to a method already having generic type in scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have a method:

```
object Object1{
def method1[T >: Null: ClassTag: TypeTag](input: String): T = {
    val m = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
    m.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    Option(input)
      .map(m.readValue[T](_, classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]))
      .orNull
  }
}
```

I want to dynamically pass type to this method, I have tried it like:

```
import spark.implicits._

def getHome[T](s: Dataset[Sig], someString: String): Dataset[T] = {
    s.filter(s => (s.sType == someString))
      .map(s => Object1.method1[T](s.sDetails))
  }
```

But I am getting error: **No implicits found for parameter evidence$6**.
I have also imported implicits. What is the best way to implement above logic in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a value of a wider type `T` to a narrower type `T >: Null: ClassTag: TypeTag` and this is never OK. You have to add the same (or better) type constraints to the type parameter of `getHome`:

```
def getHome[T >: Null: ClassTag: TypeTag](s: Dataset[Sig], someString: String): Dataset[T] = {
```

It also feels like `method1` should be using the `Manifest` typeclass rather than `ClassTag` and `TypeTag`. This might simplify things, so check the docs for `ScalaObjectMapper`.

Comment: `Manifest` is deprecated,  but this can be simplified as it is: `TypeTag` is not needed at all, and `classTag` does not need to be mentioned in vain: just `Option(input).map(m.readValue[T])` should work.

Comment: The [latest version of ObjectMapper](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.13.0-RC3/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper.html) still uses `Manifest` but perhaps there are implicit conversions from `TypeTag`?

Comment: From `ClassTag`, yeah ... `Manifest` is a subclass of `ClassTag`, but I am not sure how it works the other way ... magic :)

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced use of implicits is indistinguishable from Magic :)

Comment: mystery solved: it doesn't actually work :D Has to be `Manifest` after all ...